# LINQ to SQL bug (or very strange feature) when using IQueryable, foreach, and multiple Where

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I ran into a scenario where LINQ to SQL acts very strangely. I would like to know if I'm doing something wrong. But I think there is a real possibility that it's a bug.

The code pasted below isn't my real code. It is a simplified version I created for this post, using the Northwind database.

A little background: I have a method that takes an `IQueryable` of `Product` and a "filter object" (which I will describe in a minute). It should run some "Where" extension methods on the `IQueryable`, based on the "filter object", and then return the `IQueryable`.

The so-called "filter object" is a `System.Collections.Generic.List` of an anonymous type of this structure: `{ column = fieldEnum, id = int }`

The fieldEnum is an enum of the different columns of the `Products` table that I would possibly like to use for the filtering.

Instead of explaining further how my code works, it's easier if you just take a look at it. It's simple to follow.

```
enum filterType { supplier = 1, category }
public IQueryable<Product> getIQueryableProducts()
{
    NorthwindDataClassesDataContext db = new NorthwindDataClassesDataContext();
    IQueryable<Product> query = db.Products.AsQueryable();

    //this section is just for the example. It creates a Generic List of an Anonymous Type
    //with two objects. In real life I get the same kind of collection, but it isn't hard coded like here
    var filter1 = new { column = filterType.supplier, id = 7 };
    var filter2 = new { column = filterType.category, id = 3 };
    var filterList = (new[] { filter1 }).ToList();
    filterList.Add(filter2);

    foreach(var oFilter in filterList)
    {
        switch (oFilter.column)
        {
            case filterType.supplier:
                query = query.Where(p => p.SupplierID == oFilter.id);
                break;
            case filterType.category:
                query = query.Where(p => p.CategoryID == oFilter.id);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return query;
}
```

So here is an example. Let's say the List contains two items of this anonymous type, `{ column = fieldEnum.Supplier, id = 7 }` and `{ column = fieldEnum.Category, id = 3}`.

After running the code above, the underlying SQL query of the `IQueryable` object should contain:

```
WHERE SupplierID = 7 AND CategoryID = 3
```

But in reality, after the code runs the SQL that gets executed is

```
WHERE SupplierID = 3 AND CategoryID = 3
```

I tried defining `query` as a property and setting a breakpoint on the setter, thinking I could catch what's changing it when it shouldn't be. But everything was supposedly fine. So instead I just checked the underlying SQL after every command. I realized that the first `Where` runs fine, and `query` stays fine (meaning `SupplierID = 7`) until right after the `foreach` loop runs the second time. Right after `oFilter` becomes the second anonymous type item, and not the first, the 'query' SQL changes to `Supplier = 3`. So what must be happening here under-the-hood is that instead of just remembering that `Supplier` should equal 7, LINQ to SQL remembers that Supplier should equal `oFilter.id`. But `oFilter` is a name of a single item of a `foreach` loop, and it means something different after it iterates.

Comment: Brian's got the bug nailed (it's about the evaluation time of expressions), but just a quick note that the ".AsQueryable()" on the end of your initial query is unnecessary, since db.Products is Table<Product>, which is IQueryable<Product> already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Captured Variable In Loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/c-sharp-captured-variable-in-loop)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have only glanced at your question, but I am 90% sure that you should read the first section of [On lambdas, capture, and mutability](https://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/11/12/on-lambdas-capture-and-mutability/) (which includes links to 5 similar SO questions) and all will become clear.

The basic gist of it is that the variable `oFilter` in your example has been captured in the closure by *reference* and not by *value*. That means that once the loop finishes iterating, the variable's reference is to the last one, so the value as evaluated at lambda execution time is the final one as well.

The cure is to insert a new variable inside the `foreach` loop whose scope is only that iteration rather than the whole loop:

```
foreach(var oFilter in filterList)
{
    var filter = oFilter; // add this
    switch (oFilter.column) // this doesn't have to change, but can for consistency
    {
        case filterType.supplier:
            query = query.Where(p => p.SupplierID == filter.id); // use `filter` here
            break;
```

Now each closure is over a *different* `filter` variable that is declared anew inside of each loop, and your code will run as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Working as designed. The issue you are confronting is the clash between *lexical closure* and *mutable variables*.

What you probably want to do is

```
foreach(var oFilter in filterList)
{
    var o = oFilter;
    switch (o.column)
    {
        case filterType.supplier:
            query = query.Where(p => p.SupplierID == o.id);
            break;
        case filterType.category:
            query = query.Where(p => p.CategoryID == o.id);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

When compiled to IL, the variable `oFilter` is declared *once* and used *multiply*. What you need is a variable declared separately for each use of that variable within a closure, which is what `o` is now there for.

While you're at it, get rid of that bastardized Hungarian notation :P.

Comment: "mutable variables" - isn't "o" a mutable variable?  perhaps there's a better way to describe the problem.

Comment: Good on yer for hating on Hungarian notation!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the clearest explanation I've ever seen: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx:

> Basically, the problem arises because we specify that the foreach loop is a syntactic sugar for

```
{
    IEnumerator<int> e = ((IEnumerable<int>)values).GetEnumerator();
    try
    {
        int m; // OUTSIDE THE ACTUAL LOOP
        while(e.MoveNext())
        {
            m = (int)(int)e.Current;
            funcs.Add(()=>m);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (e != null) ((IDisposable)e).Dispose();
    }
}
```

> If we specified that the expansion was

```
try
{
    while(e.MoveNext())
    {
        int m; // INSIDE
        m = (int)(int)e.Current;
        funcs.Add(()=>m);
    }
```

> then the code would behave as expected.

Answer (score -3):

The problem is that you're not appending to the query, you're replacing it each time through the foreach statement.

You want something like the PredicateBuilder - http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx