# C# Func delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I am adding range of integers (101,105) using Func<> delegate.I suppose to get 101,102,..105 as output while executing the following.But I am getting 204,204,.....
What went wrong?

```
class MainClass
    {
       static List<Func<int>> somevalues = new List<Func<int>>();
        static void Main()
        {
            foreach (int r in  Enumerable.Range(100, 105))
            {
                somevalues.Add(() => r);
            }

            ProcessList(somevalues);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        static void ProcessList(List<Func<int>> someValues)
        {
            foreach (Func<int> function in someValues)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(function());
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: Also, this is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295593/linq-query-built-in-foreach-loop-always-takes-parameter-value-from-last-iteration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See

http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!689.entry

or

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (int r in  Enumerable.Range(100, 105))
{
   int s = r;
   somevalues.Add(() => s);
}
```

I think, you will need to capture the outer variable into a temp value to achieve the output, you need. I am not sure of what is the concept called (captured variables maybe).

Answer (score 1):

THe Range method signiture is like follows:

```
Range(int start, int count);
```

you are saying "start at 100 and give me the next 105 numbers".

not, "start at 100 and finish at 105".